# Error on publish app to AppStore Xamarin.iOS build

Tags: ios, swift, xamarin, xamarin.ios

**Issue: Invalid Swift Support- The file libswiftAVFoundation.dylib doesn’t**

I have tried to resolve my issue based on the following link. but still, I'm getting the issue after uploaded in App store. Please help me resolve this issue. I'm new for Xamarin.iOS

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1nWY-RK9oXsNnlca5eSvbH9tQejLnCjismHrSy8IuDFo/edit

**Totally I have created two projects in Xamarin and works well in locally.**

```
Project 1. Xamarin Sample Binding Project 
          - Here, I have included my own Swift SDK 
Project 2. Xamarin Sample Demo Project 
          - Mapped the Binding project
```

**Generated the iPA file:-** 
 Created the IPA file for Project 2 in Xamarin. The IPA doesn't have the SwiftSupport folder. Then I have followed the above doc steps and export the IPA file using Xcode. I have extracted the IPA file and seen **swiftSupport** folder. After, I have submitted in the Appstore I'm getting the below issue.

**AppStore Failed error message:-**

> Invalid Swift Support- The file libswiftAVFoundation.dylib doesn’t
>   have the correct code signature. Make sure you’re using the correct
>   signature, rebuild your app using the current public (GM) version of
>   Xcode, and resubmit it. Don’t just modify the code signature of
>   libswiftAVFoundation.dylib.

Comment: Are the Swift frameworks you are including match the version of Xcode that Xamarin is using to build the ipa?

Comment: @SushiHangover Thanks for your Reply. My SDK swift version I have to build with Swift 4.2 in Xcode. If possible to change the version in Xamarin.iOS ?

Comment: Thank you @SushiHangover. My app is working fine now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, Luckily my app works fine.   I have just removed all swift framework lib and added the **Xamarin.Swift** lib only from the Package. That's it.

Thank you Every one

Comment: whats the size of Xamarin Swift , probably it contain all the swift libraries. that make build size bigger. Better you add swift support folder yourself with required swift libraries.